# Show/hide CircularProgressIndicator dynamically

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a screen in my app where I have few other widgets along with CircularProgressIndicator, I need help showing and hiding the progressbar whenever a task is done, without changing the state of whole screen

Comment: Wrap CircularProgressIndicator with a UniversalWidget (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/universal_widget), plug that UniversalWidget into your root screen, give it a name, then you can show/hide by calling UniversalWidget.find("name").update(visible: true) or (visible: false)

Comment: UniversalWidget solved it! Thanks @GoonNguyen

Comment: Glad it could help! Let me make that an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap **CircularProgressIndicator** with a **UniversalWidget** (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/universal_widget), plug that `UniversalWidget` into your root screen, give it a name, then you can show/hide by calling `UniversalWidget.find("name").update(visible: true)` or `(visible: false)`

Comment: This library is deprecated for 3 years and doesn't contain a nullsafety version.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use `Visibility` Widget and set the visible property to true or false according to your needs